# Par ou impar através de módulo random (Python)

Tags: python, random, módulo-python

Recentemente comecei a aprender linguagem de programação com o python, criei um "jogo" clássico para ir aprendendo com random.randint para o usuário tentar adivinhar qual foi o número escolhido pela máquina.

Tentei fazer o mesmo mas dessa vez para adivinhar se o computador escolheu um número PAR ou ÍMPAR e não estou conseguindo entender muito bem como implementar.

Criei apenas de forma simplificada e consegui o resultado, mas não entendi muito bem como faço para verificar se é par ou ímpar pelo módulo random

```
# Este é apenas o programa simples sem utilizar random    
numero = int(input('Digite um número qualquer: '))    
resultado = numero % 2 # Pega o resto do número    
if resultado == 0:
    print('O número {} é PAR'.format(numero))
else:
    print('O número {} é IMPAR'.format(numero))   

# O que eu pretendia fazer, mas ao invés de adivinhar o número, queria que o jogador adivinhasse se o número é par ou ímpar (Como não consegui implementar utilizei esse programa como exemplo)

import random    
from time import sleep    
r = random.randint(1,10)  # Computador gera um número aleatório de 1 a 10    

print('Pensei em um número entre 1 e 10.')
print('-=-' * 20)

user = int(input('Em que número pensei?: ')) #Jogador tenta adivinhar

print('PROCESSANDO...')
sleep(2) # Computador aguarda 2 segundos antes de continuar

if user == r:
    print('Você me venceu! eu pensei mesmo no número {}'.format(r))
else:
    print('Ganhei! O número que pensei foi {}, não {}'.format(r, user))
```

Comment: @Raphael Qual é a parte em que você está com dificuldade? Qual a sua dúvida específica?

Comment: @LINQ Boa tarde, eu não estou conseguindo implementar uma forma da máquina pensar em um número e depois o usuário adivinhar se esse número escolhido aleatoriamente pelo computador é par ou ímpar, mais ou menos da forma do jogo de adivinhação de números, mas mostrando se o computador escolheu um número par ou ímpar. Mais ou menos assim 'Você errou, o número que escolhi foi ímpar' e o número escolhido aleatoriamente

Comment: @Raphael Veja se minha resposta te esclarece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa, ao invés de comparar os dois números, comparar os dois módulos.

Perceba que, no momento da comparação, tem o seguinte código

```
if user == r:
```

Isso vai comparar **se os dois números são iguais**, o que precisamos aqui é saber se **eles têm o mesmo módulo**.

Note também que eu não mudei as mensagens de sucesso ou falha, ainda dá a entender que o usuário acertou exatamente o número que  o computador "pensou", mas isso é detalhe.

```
import random    
from time import sleep    
r = random.randint(1,10)  # Computador gera um número aleatório de 1 a 10    

print('Pensei em um número entre 1 e 10.')
print('-=-' * 20)

user_input = int(input('Em que número pensei?: ')) #Jogador tenta adivinhar

print('PROCESSANDO...')
sleep(2) # Computador aguarda 2 segundos antes de continuar

if (user_input % 2) == (r % 2):
    print('Você me venceu! eu pensei mesmo no número {}'.format(r))
else:
    print('Ganhei! O número que pensei foi {}, não {}'.format(r, user_input))
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/Myg8)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado LINQ! Eu havia testado o if com % 2 no input e no 'r' porém eu havia esquecido de utilizar os parêntesis...hehe :x
Foi muito bem explicado, obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Mas funciona também sem os parênteses. Eu pus pra não ficar confuso. De qualquer forma, bom ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu devo ter mexido em alguma coisa no código na hora da mudança dos prints e não percebi e devo ter afetado o if.
Mas de qualquer forma ainda não estava entendendo muito bem a implementação  de resto com o random, obrigadão!